# What does OSStatus Error -50 mean?

Tags: ios, keychain

I am writing some keychain code on iOS. When I try to insert an item in keychain I get error -50.

What does OSStatus error -50 mean?

Comment: `errSecParam = -50, /* One or more parameters passed to a function where not valid. */`

Comment: where can I find a full list of the errors? thanks!

Comment: `Security.framework/SecBase.h` or here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/SecurityFrameworkReference/_index.html, under the _Keychain Services_

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's  `errSecParam`, indicating one or more of your parameters is wrong.

Here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/index.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/errSecParam

Answer (score 9):

If you are adding a password to the keychain make sure you pass it as Data and not String, otherwise you will get an OSStatus error -50.

```
static func savePassword(password: Data, account: String) throws -> OSStatus {
    let query = [
        kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword as String,
        kSecAttrAccount as String: account,
        kSecValueData as String: password
        ] as [String: Any]

    SecItemDelete(query as CFDictionary)

    return SecItemAdd(query as CFDictionary, nil)
}
```

Comment: SecItemDelete(query as CFDictionary)  the line which resolved my issue, Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Error `-50` is a `errSecParam`, and means that at least one of the parameters you passed in a function was/are not valid.

This can be due to type differences, or perhaps an invalid value.
[See this page on the Apple site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/index.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/errSecParam) to read the official documentation from Apple on `errSecParam`.